# How to show a Unix-time in a local time format

Tags: php, javascript, datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp

I have a php variable say `$expTime` (which has a unixtime say-1359683953) . I want to display this variable on the client side(in a proper time format according to his local time) . I am so confused between the UTC ,GMT , DST all that things. Can anyone suggest a solution for this using php or javascript please.

when I am using `echo date('h:i M d/y',$expTime)` it is showing me a wrong time.

How I am saving the time to database: 
    `var exp_day= parseInt($("#exp_day").val());` 
    `var exp_hrs= parseInt($("#exp_hrs").val());` 
    `var exp_min= parseInt($("#exp_min").val());` 
    `var exp_time = (exp_day*24*60*60) + (exp_hrs*60*60) + (exp_min*60) ;` 
then I posted the exp_time using ajax to a php file -
    `$expTime = time() + $_POST["exp_time"];`

What I am retrieving from the database is $expTime . This $expTime I want to display it on the all the clients system according to there local time zone (also by making sure the day light saving)

Comment: How are you determining the timezone of the client? Are you relying on Javascript (i.e. the client's system clock), or is the client explicitly providing you with the preferred timezone?

Comment: @fireeyedboy , I have updated my question explain g how I saved the time to database. Waiting for you reply ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNIX time values are usually UTC seconds since epoch. Javascript [time values](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) are UTC milliseconds since the same epoch. The ECMA-262 [Date.prototype.toString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2) method automatically generates a string representing the local time and takes account of daylight saving if it applies.

You can also use [Date](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9) methods to create your own formatted string, they also return local time and date values. There are also UTC methods if you want to work in UTC.

To do this on the client, just provide a UTC time value from the server and then all you need in javascript is:

```
var timeValue = 1359683953;  // assume seconds
var date = new Date(timeValue * 1000);  // convert time value to milliseconds

alert(date); //  Fri 01 Feb 2013 11:59:13 GMT+1000
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way I can do the same in php and just echo it out .

Comment: Yes, but then the server needs to know the timezone of each and every user and whether daylight saving time applies.

Comment: I have tried using your code but now its saying invalid date. I have updated my question on top ( I have explained how I am saving the time to database)

Comment: The code as posted works in every ECMA-262 compliant host (which should include every browser back to NN & IE 4 and probably earlier). Perhaps the time value you are supplying isn't valid? What do you get in the client (browser?)?

Answer (score 2):

Use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with [timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php):

```
$datetime = new DateTime('@1359683953');
echo $datetime->format('h:i M d/y') . "<br>";
$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
echo $datetime->format('h:i M d/y');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QWfGj0)

Comment: When providing `DateTime` with a unix timestamp, you need to prepend the timestamp with an at-sign [`@`]. Then, if you have that right, providing `DateTime::__construct()` with the additional `DateTimeZone` argument, has no effect, since a unix timestamp is always UTC.

Comment: @fireeyedboy doesn't the DateTime->format() method use the DateTimeZone provided to show local time, even when the DateTime was created with a unix (UTC) timestamp?

Comment: @Anton No, you have to explicitly convert it, after construction, using `DateTime::setTimezone()`. See the note in the "timezone" paragraph in [this section of the `DateTime` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php#refsect1-datetime.construct-parameters) as well.

Comment: Thank you. And I do appreciate you taking the time to explain the downvote as I learned something tonight. :)

Comment: @JohnConde You're welcome. But, to be fair, there's probably a little bit more involved for OP to get to a proper solution, since OP hasn't stated how OP determines the timezone of the client. If OP wants to rely on Javascript then this PHP solution will probably not suffice. If the client explicitly provided OP with a timezone (upon registration, for instance), then the PHP solution could work.

Comment: Hi , Thanx for the reply. could you please tell why `$val = $expiryTime;` ** `$datetime = new DateTime('@'.$val);` ** this code(the bolded) is not working on my php page.