# how convert unixtime to yy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript, date, unix-timestamp

I've been searching how to convert UNIXTIME to YY-MM-DD format using javascript, but so far I've only found methods to do it the other way around (YY-MM-DD to UNIXTIME).

Is there any method already incorporated in jquery or something to do this work?

Thanks!!

Comment: Make a new Date object with your Unix timestamp, then you can extract all the info you need with the date methods and make a string of your choice. Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Closely related searches: [Convert UNIX Time to mm/dd/yy hh:mm (24 hour) in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187790/convert-unix-time-to-mm-dd-yy-hhmm-24-hour-in-javascript) and [How to show a Unix-time in a local time format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617305/how-to-show-a-unix-time-in-a-local-time-format)

Answer (score 1):

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} var today = yyyy.toString().substr(2,2)+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = today;
```

This will do the job ..

Of course your new Date() will be your unix time..

http://jsfiddle.net/UpMU5/

Comment: Your output produces "M-D-YY` and not `YY-MM-DD` (in fact your jsfiddle produces `M/D/YY`)

Comment: Updated it now .. Very simple to change... Very harsh for a downvote.

Comment: The down vote is to bring it to your attention and will be removed when fixed. Your update now produces `YY-M-D` and not `YY-MM-DD`

Comment: you were right! Damn these late nights! ;) Updated ! - By the way your answer is probably better, this is just a way of doing without any extra libs!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library like [moments.js](http://momentjs.com/) or in POJS

> Moments.js
>
> A 5.5kb javascript date library for parsing, validating, manipulating,
>   and formatting dates.
>
> [unixtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)
>
> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing instances in
>   time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since
>   00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January
>   1970,[note 1] not counting leap seconds.[note 2] It is used widely in
>   Unix-like and many other operating systems and file formats. Due to
>   its handling of leap seconds, it is neither a linear representation of
>   time nor a true representation of UTC.[note 3] Unix time may be
>   checked on some Unix systems by typing date +%s on the command line.
>
> [Javascript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
>
> Summary
>
> Creates JavaScript Date instances which let you work with dates and
>   times.

Javascript

```
function padZero(number) {
    if (number < 10) {
        number = "0" + number;
    }

    return number;
}

function unixtime2YYMMDD(unixtime) {
    var milliseconds = unixtime * 1000,
        dateObject = new Date(milliseconds),
        temp = [];

    temp.push(dateObject.getUTCFullYear().toString().slice(2));
    temp.push(padZero(dateObject.getUTCMonth() + 1));
    temp.push(padZero(dateObject.getUTCDate()));

    return temp.join("-");
}

console.log(unixtime2YYMMDD(1372069271));
```

Output

```
13-06-24
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/PFwRM/)